# add event tracking to mediaelement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js, event-tracking

I know that mediaelement.js enables event tracking with google analytics however, as is always the way my project demands event tracking using sitecatalyst.

Has anyone modified/extended mediaelement.js to expose event callbacks that I can hook my sitecatalyst tags into?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the timerupdate event to trigger at an interval and report to ex sitecatalyst.

```
window.player = new MediaElementPlayer('video', {
        enablePluginDebug: true,
        alwaysShowControls: true,
        autosizeProgress : true,
        timerRate : 10,
        features: ['progress'],

        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {

            // Event listeners

            mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (e) {
                console.log('Report to sitecatalyst here');
            }, false);
       }
});
```